# How to display image in list component in Flash cs4?

Tags: flash, list

I used a List Component in my flash, and now I have to display image in the List component instead just text.   Is there any solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

Lee Brimelow has a good example of using images as [icons in the list component](http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=11)

Alternatively you might want to consider using a TileList component (search for "Displaying images with the TileList component").